# Biological 'Black Box' - how to test for underlying logic?

Tags: simulation, theory, modeling, biopotential

Firstly, I am a neuroscientist - so bear with me!

I have a collection of connected brain cells (network) and a means of recording the electrical output, as well as manipulating the input to the network in a temporally and spatially precise manner.

I want to know how the circuit as a whole, and eventually the individual components (individual brain cells), work with various inputs.

I think what I'm wanting is analogous to testing the frequency-response of a simple resistor-capacitor filter.

Whilst a frequency-response is a likely property of my brain cell network, I want to know of other means (tests) which would reveal more information about the 'black box'. Perhaps, inverted patterns of input stimulation, simultaneous activation and inactivation of different inputs.

Does any of this make sense? Any ideas or direction of a text would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what I should bare here, but in systems of any complexity, testing that sort of thing exhaustively rapidly gets out of hand because of the number of permutations. If you had some criteria for "interesting" behavior, maybe you could use Monte Carlo testing and a steepest descent algorithm to home in on it. Otherwise, I'm afraid your testing will have to depend on your understanding of the black box, unless it's an extraordinarily simple black box with low double-digit elements.

Comment: What you're trying to do is extraordinarily difficult. If I remember correctly, only very simple organisms like earthworms have had successful neural pathways mapped, but only because they tend to have ~100 neurons. Honestly, unless you are taking one neuron as an input and one as an output and don't mind a very simple "equivalent circuit," this would be exceptionally difficult. Neurons, I'm pretty sure, do not act like a simple, first-order RC filter.

If you meet those conditions then you could run frequency and amplitude sweeps at the input neuron, then just monitor the output neuron.

Comment: What they all said, alas. Also consider that time and network-memory-capability are probably inseparable elements.  | If I wanted maximum information from such an arrangement I'd look to recording all inputs and outputs at time intervals small enough to capture all significant variations. Values for "small enough" and "significant" are left as an exercise for the researcher :-). ie a data logger allowing subsequent data-processing s desired seems like an excellent start.

Comment: A group of neurons and their interconnections is neither linear nor time-invariant, so most of the techniques used in electronic circuit analysis are going to be of no help to you. You're going to have to come up with a hypothesis that describes how you think your system behaves, build a mathematical model that implements that hypothesis, and then see whether your model and the real world agree. But when they don't, you're on you own as far as what to change in your model.

Comment: There are PLENTY of linear systems based models of neural systems (eg, the vestibular system), and many nonlinear models. Huge research literature spanning almost 50 years, tons of books, etc.  This is not new, not limited to small systems,and accesible from the level of one neuron to large distributed cortical systems.  Every method mentioned so far can be a reasonable appproach, plus dozens more.

Answer (score 3):

There's a mathematics of neural networks you need to look into, and many other nonlinear techniques.  In short, you have a huge literature to catch up on.  You need to be much more specific about what you're trying to accomplish before you'll get any real help, but I suggest you look into the journal "Neural Networks" to help you start sorting this out.  It might help you to pick a field where such tools are often used, like the epilepsy literature, and look to see what applies to your field.

Generically, all the methodology you might choose to use comes under the heading "Computational Neuroscience".  The best general purpose intro I know of that will walk you through many types of models is Kristoff Koch's "Methods in Neuronal Modeling".  It's a hair dated, but should at least teach you a bit of the language of what you're trying.  Another possible ref is Tom Anastasio's "[Tutorial on Neural Systems Modeling](http://www.sinauer.com/tutorial-on-neural-systems-modeling.html#table_of_contents)" (Tom is actually a friend of mine since before I ever considered neuroscience).

If you're real interested and willing to put resources behind the interest, I've heard very good things about some of the Woods Hole courses, like http://hermes.mbl.edu/education/courses/special_topics/mcn.html

People study for years to get where your're trying to go.  The best recommendation you're likely to get is to hunt high and low for a collaborator to help you on your way.  Figure out what you bring to the table in such an arrangement, and find an engineer who might be interested in your field , likely a biomedical engineer.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Will look into Neual Networks and think of potential collaborators. Do you know someone (yourself???) interested?

Comment: I'd be happy to take a peek at what you've got going, but I've got a bunch on my table right now, and my career is shifting away from those type of pursuits.  I think any research plans in this direction for you would need somebody experienced in the PI role, as you're some years away from being fundable in these areas.

Comment: That is, unless you can make these pursuits a minor Aim on a larger grant.

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of inputs that correspond to a set of outputs. You want to *predict* how the circuit works with various inputs. This is a classic machine learning problem.

Further more, since you are using a network of brain cells, 'neural networks' may be a good model for your system. You could set up the nodes to mimic the activation function of the cells, set up the layers so that you have a similar number of connections, inputs, outputs, etc.

The next step is to train the network with your known inputs and measured outputs. Training the neural network involves adjusting the weights between nodes, maybe even dropping out nodes or connections, so that when the set of training inputs is applied you get close to the correct outputs.

Once the network is trained, you can apply new inputs and see what comes out. You can verify the network by then applying the same new inputs to the real brain cells and see if the same output is obtained. This can be done retrospectively by only using half the already collected data to train, and the other half to test. The network topology can be adjusted until it gives you a really nice fit.

I think you need a mathematician / statistician / engineer who is experienced in machine learning with neural networks. I'm guessing you are located at a university? This would make a great collaborative project. It will require some time though.

Comment: Just how applicable Neural Networks would be would really depend on how well the system under investigation can be crammed into the morphologies used in that sort of simulation, and many neural systems tend to be a good deal sparser in terms of connectivity than those models.

Comment: @ScottSeidman yes true, I removed 'ideal' from the answer to reflex this. I image brains have the equivalent of many hidden layers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to learn a lot more about how nerve cells work before attempting experiments like this. I can't imagine why you think "frequency response is a likely property" as it is for an RC network. They respond to very specific kinds of stimuli, and thinking about their behavior as though they were simple electrical circuits is not going to get you very far.

Comment: Please don't judge my understanding of neuroscience by the question which I have posted or the language I have used. I have >10 years experience recording electrical activity from brain cells. I have some new hardware available to me which allows me to manipulate many spatially-defined inputs to a single brain cell, and therefore allows me to research in new directions - hence the question.